# Is it possible to update a field value in one table based on data inserted into various other tables?

Tags: mysql, update

Suppose I have a table representing clients. There is a field called last_active in the table which contains a time stamp. 
When a client uses the database they can insert data into one of four different tables. 
Is there an efficient way to update the time stamp based on the user adding/updating data to one of the other four tables?

Currently I'm using a prepared statement to update the field and I run it directly after the prepared statements that add to or modify the other tables. Is this an efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider switching the problem around...

Have a TIMESTAMP with suitable DEFAULT in each table.  Have it automatically set on UPDATE or INSERT.

Then, during the SELECT, JOIN the 4 tables and get GREATEST(t1.ts, t2.ts, ...) to find out the latest TIMESTAMP of the 4.

(I have been bitten by TIMESTAMP DEFAULTs -- they get updated when I am not expecting it.  I would rather take control and change/set the ts in the code.)

Comment: OK. I'm writing a service that will need to check the database for the last update event of hundreds of clients (initially, then hopefully thousands in the next year or so), each of which could be saving multiple events every 30 or so seconds across these four tables. I'll need to check the time stamp every couple of minutes maybe. I suppose this way is still more efficient with large data sets? Especially if each insert/update statement has a corresponding update statement for the relevant time stamp. Would that be correct?

Comment: A thousand-way JOIN?  Not cool.  In fact there is a limit of about 61.  Alternatives... (1) Update some centralized timestamp at the same time you update the client's record.  (2) have a robot scan all clients -- and save the MAX somewhere; this has the flaw of being a little out of date.

Comment: My initial idea was to have a 'last_contacted' `Timestamp`  field in the client table and update that every time a client contacted the server. But we've modified the database since, so each table has a `Timestamp` field, and I'm doing a `SELECT id, MAX(time_stamp)` and `UNION` on each table, then querying the result for the maximum value of `time_stamp` for each `id`.